# Is there a comprehensive list of types of Samadhi?

Tags: samadhi, pali

Is there a comprehensive list of different types of Samadhi (in Pali, Sanskrit, English and/or otherwise) related to Buddhism?

Answer (score 2):

I did an in depth research going through a digital search of the pali suttas and compiling a comprehensive list of every type of usage of
☂️ Samādhi: broad umbrella term in every type of usage in EBT.
https://lucid24.org/sted/8aam/8samadhi/nuance/index.html

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much! This was and is a very needed resource.